# Limit calculation, justification for use of l'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-sum

Determine the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t $$

I would use the l'Hospital's rule, but for that I need to be able to justify that the integral tends to $\infty$. Not concerned with the calculation itself, rather need to justify the use of l'Hospital's rule.

Calculating out the series looks to be very tedious, no doubt it will answer the question, but is there a faster way?

Comment: The integrand is bigger than $(\cos 1) / t^2$. Now, take out the constant from the integral and see that it is divergent.

Comment: If you really want to use L'Hospital's rule you just need to write the $x$ as $1/(1/x)$ so that the denominator has $1/x \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^{+}$. The LHR only requires the denominator to tend to $\infty$. There is no need to worry about numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos(t)=1+o(1)\implies \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}=\frac{1}{t^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\implies \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\sim_0\frac{1}{t^2} \implies \int_x^1\frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\mathrm d t=+\infty.$$
Therefore $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_x^1 \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\mathrm d t=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_x^1 \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\mathrm d t}{\frac{1}{x}}\underset{Hospital}{=}...=1.$$

The fact that you can use l'Hospital is because you have an indetermination of the type $\frac{\infty }{\infty }$.

Comment: Yes, I understand why I can use l'H, the o-notation bit is a tad confusing, haven't used it that much. $o(1)$ means that $t$ is increasing faster than $1$?

Comment: $f=o(g)$ at $x=a$ if $\lim_{a}\frac{f}{g}=0$.

Comment: Ah, okay, now it makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may observe that, as $x \to0$,
$$
x\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t=x (1-x)\times \frac{\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t}{1-x}\sim x (1-x)\times \left(-\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right)
$$ and you may conclude easily.

We have used

> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\to f'(a)
> $$

with $f'(x)=-\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2}$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid De l'Hopital by noticing that $\frac{\cos t}{t^2} = \frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{2\sin^2(t/2)}{t^2}$, where the last part is a continuous and bounded function on $(0,1]$, hence, by exploiting $\int\frac{dt}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{t}$:
$$ \int_{x}^{1}\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,dt = -1+\frac{1}{x}-C+O(x) $$
(where $C=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\sin^2(t/2)}{t^2}\,dt$) and that clearly implies:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\int_{x}^{1}\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,dt = \color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: this one is way simpler. +1